# Getting random, unformatted page on Template/Channel Entry Edit

Tags: ee2, templates, admin, system, administration

**Quick run down of the site:**

- EE 2.6.1
- Media Temple Grid Service

Since we moved the site to their production server, we've noticed that we will randomly receive a page that is missing any formatting and has only bracketed information. For example, when we update a template we will sometimes get this whether or not we use "Update" or "Update and Finished":

```
{"message_success":"Template Has Been Updated"}
```

If we update a channel entry and use "Update and Finished" the system will return a bracketed list of entries within the channel but no admin. The only way to get around the issue I have found is to strip everything after the ?S= key so I can use the admin. If I don't, when I try to log in or go to the admin login page I just get this returned on the page with nothing else:

```
C=login
```

It is important to note that the only EE developer that we had was let go and I have little-to-no experience managing an EE site beyond basic templating and the like so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Media Temple Admin, go to PHP Settings.  Within PHP Settings, your particular EE site domain it is probably set to use FastCGI currently.  Change it to CGI Stable and your problem will be solved.